# <1MBps 4K read/write HDD issue

Tags: hard-drive, performance, io

I bought a netbook, Windows Starter - it seemed really slow right from the start, so I removed all the bloatware, but it remained slow still. So I tested disk I/O with CrystalDiskMark and got

```
4k read: 0.296 MB/s
4k write: 0.842 MB/s
```

Seq read/write was allright, with 50 megs per sec. Disk in question is Seagate ST320LM000 HM321HI.

How to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Fix what exactly? What is your question?

Comment: I presume that the fact the disk is reading/writing random data under 1MBps is causing the slow performance? If that is so, what to do to improve 4k read/write.

Comment: You bought a netbook running Windows Starter edition. What specification is the netbook? By definition, they are slow machines, running a minimal setup of Windows due to resource constraints. I think your question is asked and answered by this fact.

Comment: Mate, no hard disk should have a 200kB 4k r/w speed.

Comment: Then your hard drive is faulty, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 5400RPM drive with 8mb cache -- pretty low-end, to put it nicely -- and which is also known for early failures.  Look at the specs on the HN-M320MBB drive, which is the original model for this now-Seagate-labelled drive, though you should be getting much better.  Make sure you don't still have something like antivirus software slowing things down.  The drive specs are at http://www.samsung.com/global/system/business/hdd/prdmodel/2011/6/9/156582m8.pdf :

Average Seek time (typical)
12 ms
Linear Shock (1/2 sine pulse)
Average Latency
5.6 ms
Operating, 2ms
325 G
Data Transfer Rate
Non-operating, 2ms
750 G
Media to/from Buffer (Max.)
145 Mbits/s
Vibration (swept sine, 1/4 octave per minute)
Buffer to/from Host (Max.)
300 MB/s
Operating
1 .5 Grms
Drive Ready Time (typical)3
4 sec